# Firing an asyncronous HTTP Handler from outside of IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, comet

I have an Async HTTP Handler which serves as a [Comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29) request/response, hosted in ASP.NET on IIS7.

The handler receives a request, then waits for an event to be called before sending the response back to the client.

Is it possible to call the event from outside of this ASP.NET application, in a separate web service hosted on the same web server?

I can think of a few ways (such as locally calling another HTTP handler on the same application), but this seems quite dirty. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: sounds like you will have to create some CallBacks take a look here to see if this can be of help http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163725.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up calling the handler using a local HTTP request. The request was actually quite cheap in the end. Plus, we've decided we may need to move this functionality to another server in the future, which should be quite easy with a simple HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR), you could setup a Hub for your application to communicate with various endpoints.